# What is the purpose of DatumWriter in Avro

Tags: java, avro

`Avro` website has an example:

```
DatumWriter<User> userDatumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<User>(User.class);
DataFileWriter<User> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<User>(userDatumWriter);
dataFileWriter.create(user1.getSchema(), new File("users.avro"));
dataFileWriter.append(user1);
dataFileWriter.append(user2);
dataFileWriter.append(user3);
dataFileWriter.close();
```

What is the purpose of `DatumWriter<User>`? I mean what it does provide? It provides `write` method, but instead of using it we use `DataFileWriter`. Can someone explain the design purpose of it?

Comment: It looks like [decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to me.

Answer (score 6):

The DatumWriter class responsible for translating the given data object into an avro record with a given schema (which is extracted in your case from the User class).

Given this record the DataFileWriter is responsible to write it to a file.